# does the equivalence class of an element in a set is the set itself?

Tags: calculus, equivalence-relations

what does equivalence class mean?

I am trying to understand I think that I am a little confused so let's take this example:

Suppose that we have the relation $2x+3y$ is a number less than or equal 20 on the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ this relation is equivalence relation because it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, now let's get the equivalence class for each of the elements:

$[1]$ = $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, [2] = $\{2,1,3,4\}$, $[3]$ = $\{3, 1, 2, 4\}$, $[4]$ = $\{4, 1, 2, 3\}$.

have I calculated the equivalence relations correctly or I made some mistakes and if the answer is that you calculated them correctly this will push me to ask ***does the equivalence class of an element in a set is the  set itself?***

Comment: If I am following you, then $4$ is not equivalent to itself under your relation (as $2*4+3*4=20$).  Hence your relation is not reflexive.  Or am I confused?

Comment: sorry, less than or equal.

Comment: Ah, I see that you edited your question.   Then, you are correct, in your example every element is equivalent to any other element.  I would say that this was still an equivalence relation, just a trivial one.  Of course this does not mean that all equivalence relations are trivial!

Comment: If you want a non-trivial equivalence relation on your set, try (for example): $n\sim m$ if $2 |(n-m)$.

Comment: Or, more generally, take any partition of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into disjoint nonempty subsets, and define $n$ and $m$ to be equivalent iff $n$ and $m$ are in the same subset.

Comment: Thanks all, @Bungo your example is clear so thanks a lot.

Comment: @lulu thanks too but I am a programmer not a mathematics student so it is difficult for me to read this relation n∼m if 2|(n−m) :( so I hop to simplify it for me.

Comment: No problem.  I was proposing an equivalence relation where $n$ is held to be equivalent to $m$ if $2$ divides the difference between them, $n-m$.  In your set, this would mean that $1\sim 3$ and $2 \sim 4$. So the equivalence classes are {${1,3}$} and {${2,4}$}.  As @Bungo points out, there is no need for any sort of algebraic definition...you can take any partition of the subsets.  Still, I think it's nice to see examples arising out of algebra or arithmetic.

Comment: @lulu thanks a lot